# Cut Vertex (or) Articulation Point

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

can anybody please provide me a detailed pictorial explanation of what is happening inside this code?

```
int adjMatrix[256][256];
int dfsnum[256], num = 0, low[256];
void cutVertices(int u) {
    low[u] = dfsnum[u] = num++;
    for(int v = 0; v<256; ++v) {
        if(adjMatrix[u][v] && dfsnum[v] == -1) {
            if(low[v] > dfsnum[u]) 
                printf("CutVertex:%d",u);
            low[u] = min(low[u], low[v]);
       }
       else {
           low[u] = min(low[u], dfsnum[v]);
   }
   }
```

This is actually a Method of finding a cutvertices using DFS search resultant tree.

the method says that the root vertex is a cut vertex if and only if it has at least two children. A non-root vertex u is a cut vertex if and only if there is a son v of u such that low(v) >= dfsnum(u).
where low(v) = lowest numbered vertex that reachable from v by taking zero or more tree edges and tehn possibly one back edge(in that order).

Comment: Text explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/ Visualization: https://visualgo.net/en/dfsbfs

Comment: @Photon That Visualization website is amazing, thank you for that, it's most appreciated.